# Parsing an xml file with an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, xml-parsing, xmltodict

I have an `xml` file of the form:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Root>
        <Phonemic>and</Phonemic>
        <Phonetic>nd</Phonetic>
        <Description/>
        <Start>0</Start>
        <End>8262</End>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Phonemic>comfortable</Phonemic>
        <Phonetic>comfetebl</Phonetic>
        <Description>adj</Description>
        <Start>61404</Start>
        <End>72624</End>
    </Root>
</NewDataSet>
```

I need to process it so that, for instance, when the user inputs `nd`, the program matches it with the `<Phonetic>` tag and returns `and` from the `<Phonemic>` part. I thought maybe if I can convert the xml file to a dictionary, I would be able to iterate over the data and find information when needed.

I searched and found [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) which is used for the same purpose:

```
import xmltodict
with open(r'path\to\1.xml', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fd:
    obj = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
```

Running this gives me an `ordered dict`:

```
>>> obj
OrderedDict([('NewDataSet', OrderedDict([('Root', [OrderedDict([('Phonemic', 'and'), ('Phonetic', 'nd'), ('Description', None), ('Start', '0'), ('End', '8262')]), OrderedDict([('Phonemic', 'comfortable'), ('Phonetic', 'comfetebl'), ('Description', 'adj'), ('Start', '61404'), ('End', '72624')])])]))])
```

Now this unfortunately hasn't made things simpler and I am not sure how to go about implementing the program with the new data structure. For example to access `nd` I'd have to write:

```
obj['NewDataSet']['Root'][0]['Phonetic']
```

which is ridiculously complicated. I tried to make it into a regular dictionary by `dict()` but as it is nested, the inner layers remain ordered and my data is so big.

Comment: How would converting to a regular dictionary make any difference? You will still have as many layers of keys. What *exactly* is the problem; do you just not like the `OrderedDict.__repr__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are accessing this as `obj['NewDataSet']['Root'][0]['Phonetic']`, IMO, you are not doing it right.

Instead, you can do the following

```
obj = obj["NewDataSet"]
root_elements = obj["Root"] if type(obj) == OrderedDict else [obj["Root"]] 
# Above step ensures that root_elements is always a list
for element in root_elements:
    print element["Phonetic"]
```

Even though this code looks much more longer, the advantage is that it will be lot more compact and modular once you start dealing with sufficiently large xml.

PS: I had the same issues with `xmltodict`. But instead of parsing using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) to parse the xml files, xmltodict was much easier to work with as the code base was smaller, and I didn't have to deal with other inanities of the xml module.

***EDIT***

Following code works for me

```
import xmltodict
from collections import OrderedDict

xmldata = """<NewDataSet>
    <Root>
        <Phonemic>and</Phonemic>
        <Phonetic>nd</Phonetic>
        <Description/>
        <Start>0</Start>
        <End>8262</End>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Phonemic>comfortable</Phonemic>
        <Phonetic>comfetebl</Phonetic>
        <Description>adj</Description>
        <Start>61404</Start>
        <End>72624</End>
    </Root>
</NewDataSet>"""

obj = xmltodict.parse(xmldata)
obj = obj["NewDataSet"]
root_elements = obj["Root"] if type(obj) == OrderedDict else [obj["Root"]] 
# Above step ensures that root_elements is always a list
for element in root_elements:
    print element["Phonetic"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the last line should be `print element[0]['Phonemic']` otherwise it would complain that the indices should be integers not `str`.

Comment: @novice66 no it won't be, reason being the index is taken care of because of the for loop I use. Did you face any issues trying out the code?

Comment: I just ran it (in Python 3, having added the parentheses around `print`) and I got the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @novice66 Check edits. I am on python 2, so that may be causing it.

Comment: With your last statement, comparison to `etree` you mean that `xmltodict` is slimmer regarding its code and therefore easier to handle as compared to others that are more blown?

Answer (score 6):

You can actually avoid conversion to OrderedDict by setting an additional keyword paramter:

```
obj = xmltodict.parse(xmldata, dict_constructor=dict)
```

`parse` is forwarding keyword arguments to `_DictSAXHandler` and `dict_constructor` is by default set to `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

Mu's answer worked for me, the only thing I had to change was the tricky **ensure root_element is always a list** step.: -

```
import xmltodict
from collections import OrderedDict

xmldata = """<NewDataSet>
    <Root>
        <Phonemic>and</Phonemic>
        <Phonetic>nd</Phonetic>
        <Description/>
        <Start>0</Start>
        <End>8262</End>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Phonemic>comfortable</Phonemic>
        <Phonetic>comfetebl</Phonetic>
        <Description>adj</Description>
        <Start>61404</Start>
        <End>72624</End>
    </Root>
</NewDataSet>"""

obj = xmltodict.parse(xmldata)
obj = obj["NewDataSet"]
root_elements = obj["Root"] if type(obj["Root"]) == list else [obj["Root"]] 
# Above step ensures that root_elements is always a list
# Is obj["Root"] a list already, then use obj["Root"], otherwise make single element list.
for element in root_elements:
    print element["Phonetic"]
```